# Making a trigger to not create an insurance policy for a driver that has been involved in an accident

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Hello I am brand new to triggers in SQL and need some help with one. I am working with 3 tables involving drivers, car accidents, and insurance policy. What I am trying to do is create a trigger that will not allow insurance policies to be able to be made for drivers involved in an accident.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
CREATE TABLE insurance_policy(
    id INT,
    ssn_driver INT,
    expiration_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE accident(
    id INT,
    ssn_driver INT,
    accident_date DATE,
    details VARCHAR2(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES insurance_policy,
    FOREIGN KEY (ssn_driver) REFERENCES driver
);

CREATE TABLE driver(
    ssn_driver INT,
    name VARCHAR2(64),
    age INT CHECK (age>15),
    PRIMARY KEY(ssn_driver)
);

CREATE TRIGGER no_insurance_policy
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON insurance_policy
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS (select ssn_driver FROM Inserted INNER JOIN accident)
        BEGIN
            rollback transaction
            raiserror ('some message', 16, 1)
        END
    END
```

This doesn't compile, but I'm just confused on how to proceed from here. Can anyone help me out with creating this trigger?

EDIT: Here is the error

```
Error starting at line : 31 in command -
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS (select ssn_driver FROM Inserted INNER JOIN accident)
        BEGIN
            rollback transaction
            raiserror ('some message', 16, 1)
        END
    END
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 58:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , with group having intersect minus start union where
   connect
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: What is the compilation error? Please paste the exact text into your question.

Comment: This is completely incompetent idea to build an application logic into database and **especially** into trigger. What if your trigger somehow gets disabled? You should let your application BLL do these things. If you really decided to do this on database level, you should at least do all your actions inside stored procedure.

Comment: @KenY-N I have pasted it into my post

Comment: @T.S. This is for a homework assignment, I don't really have any say on that. That is just what I am asked to do.

Comment: This is not even oracle syntax `BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS (select ssn_driver FROM Inserted INNER JOIN accident)
        BEGIN
            rollback transaction
            raiserror ('some message', 16, 1)
        END
    END` you pulled it from sql server web site

Comment: @T.S Oh wow I'm sorry, I have just been trying to find a solution online as my professor has not given us very much to go off for this. How can I achieve something similar to this in oracle?

Comment: Whenever I see a completely unsuitable use of a trigger in a question I know it has been posed by some clueless professor as assessment

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to do `BEFORE` not `AFTER` insert. Then, your syntax is not even Oracle. Here is approximately what you need to do. I have not tested it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_insurance_policy
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON insurance_policy
    FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    v_accidentCout NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    Select Count(*) Into v_accidentCout 
    From accident
    Where ssn_driver = old.ssn_driver;

    If v_accidentCout > 0 Then
        raise_application_error(-12345, 'Driver has accidents');
    End If;  
END;
/
```

I would leave `commit`/`rollback` to the block that calls `insert`/`update`.